# How to skip inner loop iteration when it is equal to outer loop iteration?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a nested for loop. Essentially what I'm doing is summing the values in column 14 and 16 when 2 or more rows match with each other in columns 5, 6, 7, 10, and 11.

It may not be the most efficient code but the gist of my code is that with each iteration of k2 (reference row), I want the inner loop to compare k2 to each row inside the table aside from row k2.

Now, the problem is that with my current setup, it is possible for k2 to be compared to its own row when the value of i2 - 1 = k2 thus adding an extra value to my *sumnla* and *sumweight*.

What would be the best way for me to overcome this problem? And as you can probably tell, I am fairly new to VBA with about a month of experience so far so any tips of coding this more efficiently would be much appreciated.

```
'To consolidate materials, adding nla and weight together
For k2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary").UsedRange.Rows.Count To 2 Step -1
    sumnla = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary").Cells(k2, 14).Value
    sumweight = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary").Cells(k2, 16).Value
    valuek = k2

    For i2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary").UsedRange.Rows.Count To 2 Step -1
        If _
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary").Cells(k2, 5).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary").Cells(i2 - 1, 5).Value _
        And ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary").Cells(k2, 6).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary").Cells(i2 - 1, 6).Value _
        And ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary").Cells(k2, 7).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary").Cells(i2 - 1, 7).Value _
        And ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary").Cells(k2, 10).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary").Cells(i2 - 1, 10).Value _
        And ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary").Cells(k2, 11).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary").Cells(i2 - 1, 11).Value _
        Then
        sumnla = sumnla + ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary").Cells(i2 - 1, 14).Value
        sumweight = sumweight + ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary").Cells(i2 - 1, 16).Value
        valuek = valuek & " " & i2
        End If
    Next

    Worksheets("Procurement Table").Select
    
    'add a row at the end of the table
    Dim newrow As ListRow
    Set newrow = ListObj.ListRows.Add
        With newrow
        .Range(1) = Worksheets("Summary").Cells(k2, 10).Value
        .Range(2) = Worksheets("Summary").Cells(k2, 6).Value
        .Range(3) = Worksheets("Summary").Cells(k2, 7).Value
        .Range(4) = Worksheets("Summary").Cells(k2, 11).Value
        .Range(5) = Worksheets("Summary").Cells(k2, 12).Value
        .Range(6) = Worksheets("Summary").Cells(k2, 13).Value
        .Range(7) = 1
        .Range(8) = sumnla
        .Range(9) = "=VALUE([@EngCF])*VALUE([@BaseNLA])"
        .Range(10) = sumweight
        .Range(11) = "=VALUE([@EngCF])*VALUE([@BaseWeight])"
        .Range(12) = 1
        .Range(13) = "=VALUE([@EngFactoredWeight])*VALUE([@FabAllowance])"
        .Range(14) = valuek
        End With
Next
```

Comment: Just wrap the contents of the inner loop in `If i2 <> k2 Then ... End If`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use `goto` method to go to next loop. you can write as below.

```
if k2 = i2-1 then goto nextLoop
```

and write `nextLoop:` just before the `Next` at the end.

Also, my suggestion is about a better way to refer your worksheets. you can use a variable to refer to your worksheets. This way, you don't need to write `Worksheets("Summary")` all the time. you can do this by defining a new variable as worksheet.

```
Dim ws as Worksheet
set ws = Thisworkbook.Worksheets("Summary")
```

Comment: I'm not the one, having given you the downvote, but when I had my first programming classes, I was learnt never to use `goto`.

Comment: Yeah I know. :) But in Excel you can't just use `continue`. So you need to go for alternatives. Also, the reason of that you shouldn't use `goto` is that it makes the code less readable. But in OP's case, it won't make it more complicated. It s not a 1k lines of code after all. @Dominique

Comment: This works but I found another way that is not as dumb as my original code.. and that is to not set the initial value of my sum to the value of my reference row. As in..
    `sumnla = 0`
    `sumweight = 0`